# JsonProperty don't take value to body request

Tags: java, json, rest, selenium, lombok

I have a problem.
My code to create body for request is like that:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class CreateCountryCode {
    @JsonProperty(value = "first_value")
    private String firstValue;

    @JsonProperty(value = "second_value")
    private List<Integer> secondValue;

}
```

And problem is that created body is like that:

```
{
  "firstValue": "AAA",
  "secondValue": [
    0, 1, 2
  ]
}
```

But I want it to have structure like

```
{
  "first_value": "AAA",
  "second_value": [
    0, 1, 2
  ]
}
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Change `@JsonProperty(value = "first_value")` to `@JsonProperty("first_value")` and see if it works

Comment: Problem was on imported class.
Was:

`import com.auth0.jwt.internal.com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;`

instead

`import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;`

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are using `lombok` annotations and they generate *getters* and *setters* for you.

To change the property name's mapping, you need to manually define a *getter* with the annotation for that property. For example:

```
@JsonProperty(value = "first_value")
public String getFirstValue(){ return firstValue; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make jackson to use field instead getter method generated by lombok by using class level annotation.

```
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = ANY, getterVisibility = NONE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use a custom serializer for your library (I assume you are using somthink jackson library for serializing).
After you have defined a custom serializer you have to use it when serializing your data

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfectly fine and produces the requested output with underscores. I'm running it with Jackson 2.8.5 and Lombok 1.16.18. If possible, upgrade to these versions and try again.

I'm testing with the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    CreateCountryCode code = CreateCountryCode.builder().firstValue("foo").secondValue(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3)).build();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(code));
}
```

... producing the output:

```
{"first_value":"foo","second_value":[1,2,3]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem was on imported class. Was:

```
import com.auth0.jwt.internal.com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.Json‌​Property;
```

instead

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
```

end now works fine.
Thank you for help.